# How to display video data in vue.js template

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, ckeditor

I am saving media(video) file as part of my data collected form ckeditor5 media option which works just fine. On requesting the same saved media file in another page I am unable to display it. How would I display this media(video) data

The data is stored together with the html tags generated form ckeditor, hence on the template I am using `v-html` to display the other content such as `<p></p>,<h1></h1>` etc but the video file is not being displayed.

On querying the data this is it's format

```
"<figure class=\"media\"><oembed url=\"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=OZo_NsIFIdU\"><\/oembed><\/figure>"
```

This is what i am having problem displaying using `v-html` ...any ideas?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well after trying out a number of ways i was able to display the video by formatting a number of things using the js `.replace()` function.More about this function can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

- The `<oembed></oembed>` tags to `<ifame></iframe>` tags
- `url` part of the video to `src`
- In the video url replace the part from `watch?v=` to `embed`

In vue js you can achieve this by making a function under the `methods` property for formatting the url.An example is as follows:

```
methods:{
  modifyUrl(url) {
      let endpoint = url;
      endpoint = endpoint.replace('oembed', 'iframe');
      endpoint = endpoint.replace('url', 'src');
      endpoint = endpoint.replace('watch?v=', 'embed/');
      endpoint = endpoint.replace('oembed', 'iframe');
      return endpoint;
    },
}
```

With this a video url such as `<figure class="media"><oembed url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PX0brdmsWE"></oembed></figure>` will be transformed to `<figure class="media"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3PX0brdmsWE"></iframe></figure>`

The transformed url now can be viewed in the html section using vue.js `v-html`